# Ratios and probability mass function

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

It was given that $p_{2,3} = 2$ and $p_{0,1} = 12$

$p_{k, k+1} = \frac{P(X=k+1)}{P(X=k)}, k=0,1,2,...,n = (\frac{n-k}{k+1})(\frac{1-\theta}{\theta})$

The question was: Find $P(X \geq 2)$. Answer: $n=4, \theta = \frac{1}{4}$

My problem is I'm not getting $n=4$. What am I doing wrong. I just solved using simultaneous equations.

$p_{2,3} = (\frac{n-2}{3})(\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}) = 2$ ... (1)

$p_{0,1} = (\frac{n}{2})(\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}) = 12$ ... (2)

(2) / (1)

$(\frac{n}{2})(\frac{3}{n-2}) = 6$

$\frac{3n}{2n-4} = 6$

$3n = 6(2n-4)$

$3n = 12n - 24$

$9n = 24$

$n = \frac{8}{3}$?

Comment: You made a mistake in $P_{0,1} and see the solution below

Comment: Oh yes. How silly of me. k=0 so 0+1 is 1 for the denominator where I said 1+1

Comment: Make sure it does not happen in the test:))

Comment: Yes. I will definitely make sure of that ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

$$P_{0,1} = n\frac{1-\theta}{\theta} = 12$$
$$\frac{1-\theta}{\theta} = \frac{12}{n}$$
$$P_{2,3} = \frac{n-2}{3}\frac{1-\theta}{\theta} = 2$$
$$12n - 24 = 6n$$
$$n = 4$$
$$\frac{1-\theta}{\theta} = 3$$
$$\theta = \frac{1}{4}$$

Now that you have theta and n, you can easily find P(X>=2).  If you need help on that let me know

Thanks

Satish